# How to set the total thread limit of intel mkl in a MPI fortran program?

Tags: multithreading, mpi, openmp, intel-mkl, lsf

I run MPI fortran program on a cluster equiped with LSF job system.
My program also contains MKL function.

I know there is subroutine can set MKL thread number(for example set it to 2)

```
call mkl_set_num_threads(2)
```

As first, I thought this set the total thread number for a program. But as I tested, this seems setting thread number for each MPI process

so If I submit a job like

```
bsub -n 2 mpiexec.hydra ./a.out
```

and ssh into the node and `Top`, I found that it actually uses 4 cores, each MPI process uses 2 threads.

But this is not allowed on my cluster, because it uses cpu resources more than requested and will be killed during running.

sometimes the number of MPI processes can not divide cpu cores. For example, if a node has 24 cores, and I have 7 MPI process to run, I would like to submit like

```
bsub -n 24 mpiexec.hydra -n 7 ./a.out
```

Since MKL has `Dynamic` functionality, MKL will automatically distribute resources dynamically to 7 MPI tasks, and efficiently uses all the cpu.

But if now the cluster is kind of full. I can only request 12 cores, then

```
bsub -n 12 mpiexec.hydra -n 7 ./a.out
```

then How to set MKL to use exactly 12 mkl thread among 7 MPI task and so not get killed by system and yet remain maximun efficiency.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to launch multithreaded mpi processes in lsf?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17299904/how-to-launch-multithreaded-mpi-processes-in-lsf)

Comment: Note, that MKL defaults to use `OMP_NUM_THREADS` threads (as described [here](https://software.intel.com/en-us/articles/intel-math-kernel-library-intel-mkl-using-intel-mkl-with-threaded-applications))  You could also look at [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15177395/hybrid-mpi-openmp-in-lsf).

Comment: It's also worth noting that you should not be getting any benefit by using all 24 cores if some threads are unevenly distributed among the processes. For instance, Splitting 24 threads 7 ways at best yields 4 processes with 3 threads and 3 processes with 4 threads. Thus, you were no better off than using 21 threads where each of the 7 processes uses 3 threads.

Comment: @NoseKnowsAll Hi, NoseKnowsAll. Thank you for reminding. So you mean  directly run `mpiexec.hydra -n 7 ./a.out` on a 24 core machine with constraining thread number will be slower than `mpiexec.hydra -n 7 ./a.out -nt 3`(if -nt is option to contrain mkl thread to 3)?  So MKL dynamic can't intelligently take care the uneven case, right?

Comment: I've never relied on MKL dynamic so I don't know. That being said, it's very unlikely that your first example (even if MKL *is* intelligent) will be faster than the second example... so why avoid being explicit in this case?

Comment: @NoseKnowsAll Ok, Thank you very much